# onclick not working for a button

Tags: html

I have written this html code to move image up & down when respective button is clicked, but the image is not moving after clicking the buttons, I can't use javascript so is there any solution without using javascript?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Move Image</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img id="img" style="position:absolute; top:0%; left:0%" src="plane.png" width="300" height="100">
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById("img").style.top="0%";" style="position:absolute; top:90%; left:87%">UP</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById("img").style.top="75%";" style="position:absolute; top:90%; left:90%">DOWN</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: *I can't use javascript so is there any solution without using javascript?* You ARE using javascript already ...

Comment: " I can't use JavaScript ", but you are using it with the onclick event.

Answer (score 4):

Watch the quotes. Change to this:

```
<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("img").style.top="0%";' style="position:absolute; top:90%; left:87%">UP</button>
```

Comment: I would also go with `getElementById('img').css('top', '0');` rather

Comment: @Ortund : it would not work since`.css` is a jQuery feature.

Comment: why does everyone assume everyone else uses jQuery